# Can wifi router/modem be used to detect other wifi network in visinity

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, wifi-configuration

is there a way you can detect other wifi networks in the range of wifi router cum modem.Laptops can detect wifi networks so can wirless modem can do this ?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on if the router firmware supports it.  My old Linksys with it's stock firmware doesn't have that capability.  However, flashing it to dd-wrt, it can see other access points around for such things as bridging connections, etc.  Is there something specific you need it for and there might be a better answer.

Comment: Yes I am using D-Link 2730U and I want to study penetration testing so I want to crack my own wifi access point.

Comment: have you tried vistumbler?